# Horizontal Barcharts with text on both ends and a tick mark on the chart

Tags: bar-chart

I want to create a set of horizontal barcharts with text on both ends and a tick mark. The idea is to symbolize a value between two extremes/endpoints. Below is an illustration of what I want it to look like.

I have tried using \baritem from barchart, but I cannot figure out how to put text on both ends

[image]

Comment: @gastino-- please see the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[line width=12pt, blue] 
    (0,0)node[label=left:Introversion](a){} --   (8,0)node[label=right:Extroversion](b){};
    
\draw[line width=6pt,yellow!95!green!90!red!40]  ($(a)!0.80!(b)$)node[](c){}--++(0,1cm);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**edit for black border on the extruded yellow portion**

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[line width=12pt, blue] 
    (0,0)node[label=left:Introversion](a){} --   
    (8,0)node[label=right:Extroversion](b){};
    
\filldraw[draw=black, fill=yellow,line width=2pt, yshift=2em, xshift=14em]  
         (0pt,-5pt)+($(a)!.80!(b)$) rectangle (1,1);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```